# PFRoles, ACLs Parse.com: How to assign different access levels to an entire object graph

Tags: ios, parse-platform, acl

I'm writing an app where Users can create Networks, Networks can have many Rooms and Rooms can have many Devices. For each Network, I'd like to give Users either Admin access, Guest Access or No Access (Admins can add other users as admins or guests, can change network/room/device names etc, guests can only read network/room/device info). Admins of a network would be able to give other users either Admin access or Guest access to any network they are the an Admin of. How would I achieve this using Parse? Things I've tried:

I looked into using PFRoles. Unfortunately, you can't assign a user to be an "Admin" of a specific object graph ie a specific Network. Instead, the "Admin" role would be global to our entire app and adding a user to that role would give them Admin rights to every network.

I could use ACLs directly instead of Roles. Every time I want to change a users permissions in a network, I could walk the entire Network graph and change the ACL on each object to add/remove the user from its acl. This seems error prone.

I could create 2 roles for each network (such as prefix _Admin with the Networks object ID). But the would create 2 X (the number of Networks in the database) PFRoles.
Any ideas?